# DataFrame Write PartitionBy - couldnt parameterize multiple columns

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapr

Creating a generic code which accepts TableName and Partition columns as inputs. However facing issue while trying to write dataframe as partitioned table.

```
partAttr='product_category_id,product_id' 
pattr=partAttr.split(",")
df.write.partitionBy('"'+'","'.join(pattr)+'"').saveAsTable(dataBase+".temptable_"+deltaTable)
```

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'partition column "product_category_id", "product_id" is not defined in table `bbiuserdb`.`temptable_products_stg`, defined table columns are: product_id, product_name, product_description, product_price, product_image, product_category_id;'

However the above code works, if I have single attribute in pattr variable.

Has anyone come across similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to identify a different route, however im not sure about the reason for the above mentioned failure -

```
df.write.partitionBy(pattr[0:]).saveAsTable(dataBase+".temptable_"+deltaTable)
```

Considered the python way of complete list